# Reloading logback-spring.xml with new <maxFileSize></maxFileSize> without restarting the spring boot app

Tags: java, logging, spring-boot, logback

I have a spring boot app running on C4-Large EC2 Instance, due to a specific requirement we need to change the max size of the log files `<maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>` on demand without restarting the spring boot app. Currently logback-spring.xml is situated under resource folder and loads as we start the application.

Comment: Atleast in logback-spring.xml it is not possible

Comment: @rajadilipkolli it is possible, check my answer :)

Comment: this works , but we need to deploy code with this change. His requirement is with out restarting application he wants to change size.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, I'd recommend not using logging extensions (i.e. use logback.xml instead of logback-spring.xml) in that case, [as it does not support configuration scanning](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-logback-extensions).

Using a regular logback.xml file in an external location (not inside your jar) which can be specified using `-Dlogback.configurationFile=/path/to/config.xml`, you should be able to take advantage of logback's [configuration scanning](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#autoScan), e.g.:
`<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds">`.

That way you can have changes to your logback.xml (e.g. an updated max file size) reflected without restarting your application.

Comment: I cannot load logback separately in production, looking into mbeans now, thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Well after several attempts I was able achieve the objective-

```
<timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>${xyz.log.fsize}</maxFileSize>
```

here `${xyz.log.fsize}` is the **System property**, so in order to reload the **logback-spring.xml** without restarting the spring boot app, I have created a post call -

```
    @PostMapping("/changeSize/{size}")
        public void fsize(@PathVariable("size") String size, HttpServletResponse response) {

            try {
                System.setProperty("xyz.log.fsize", size);
                LOG.info("Change in file size is observed reloading the loggers with the latest configs...");
                InputStream logConfStream = MQConsumerController.class.getResourceAsStream(File.separator
                        + LOGBACK_SPRING_XML);
                String logConfString = CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(logConfStream));
                LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
                JoranConfigurator configurator = new JoranConfigurator();
                configurator.setContext(context);
                context.reset();
                configurator.doConfigure(new ByteArrayInputStream(logConfString.getBytes()));
                LOG.info("file size updated to -> {}", size);
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.error("Error while changing the logs file size {}", e);
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            }

        }
```

now when you start the app start it with VM argument `-Dxyz.log.fsize=10MB`

once the app is up and running, make the post call -

```
http://localhost:8080/changeSize/100MB
```

and voila! your **logback-spring.xml** is reloaded on the fly without starting the app.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution omits configuration specified in external `application.properties` file - placed on a .jar level.